# VSCode Latex-workshop: No AutoBuild for onFileChange

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

I have a problem with the AutoBuild function in VSCode Latex-Workshop:

Using

```
"latex-workshop.latex.autoBuild.run": "onFileChange"
```

the project is not build if I change (and save) my tex-file, even though the Latex Workshop logger tells me:

```
[10:54:26] File watcher: responding to change in /path/presentation.tex
[10:54:26] Parsing /path/presentation.tex
```

But nothing more happens.

---

If I change the settings to

```
"latex-workshop.latex.autoBuild.run": "onSave"
```

things work as expected:

```
[10:59:28] File watcher: responding to change in /path/presentation.tex
[10:59:28] Parsing /path/presentation.tex
[10:59:28] Auto-build /path/presentation.tex upon save.
[10:59:28] BUILD command invoked.
```

*(... building commences ...)*

---

All other settings are kept on default values.

I am using LaTeX-Workshop version 6.0.0

Thank you very much for your help!

Joschua

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to change the setting to "onSave"! I'm having the same issue with "onFileChange" with LaTeX Workshop v8.15.0. Maybe the [github issues](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues) is a better place to raise this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I experience the same problems with LaTeX Workshop 8.16.1 in vscode 1.54.3.
It is a known problem, see [this FAQ](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/FAQ#auto-build-does-not-work-sometimes).